# Evaluate integral over a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $r >0$, and $e^x-1$ is not zero on circle $|x|=r$, we need to compute the integral over a circle

$$\int_{|x|=r} \frac{e^x}{e^x -1} dx$$

My attempt: take $e^x = y$, $\frac{dy}{dx} = y$, then
\begin{align}\int_{|x|=r} \frac{e^x}{e^x -1} dx &= \int_{|ln(y)|=r}\frac{y}{y -1}\frac{dy}{y}\\
&= \int_{|ln(y)|=r} \frac{dy}{y -1}\\
&= \int_{|y|=e^r}\frac{dy}{y -1} = 2\pi i
\end{align}
  (by Cauchy integral formula)

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: No as the logarithm is not continuosly defined on any circle around zero; apply the residue theorem with care as the number of poles depends on $r$ (one at zero and two extra at each $2\pi$ jump)

Comment: You miss a subtle point   $|\ln y|=r$ does not imply that $|y|=e^r$.  For instance, $y=-1$ gives (for the principal branch of tge.logarithm) $\ln y =i\pi$ and thus $\|ln y| =pi$, but $|y|=1\not=e^{\pi}$. You should try to find the residue of the interior pole(s) in the integrand directly.